# javafxml add second circle in a pane with button

Tags: java, xml, button, javafx, move

i wrote a program that moves a circle left and right but i want to add another button "add ball" so that when I click on it will add a new circle if it was javafx or java i can do this but in javafxml i couldnt find it
controller:

```
public int step = 10; 
@FXML
private Circle c; 
@FXML
private Button b, b1; 
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    b.setOnAction(e ->{
        c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + (-step));
    });

    b1.setOnAction(e ->{
        c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + step);
    });        
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Works just the same in a controller. Just make sure the pane you want to add the `Circle` to is injected to a field too. (Changes to the scene won't be persisted though; fxml is not suited to persist data of a scene).

Comment: @sinandede Just ad the second circle the same way you added the first one but set its viability property to false and when you click the button make it viable true here is code for a combo box  cboFMO.setVisible(false)